# Is there any way in JavaScript to highlight or blink a browser tab when a custom alert sound happens?

Tags: javascript, tabs, highlight

I've done the custom alert sound part using javascript but stuck with the tab highlight.

I'm using Page Visibility API to handle making the alert sound only when the user has switched the tab. But, some users might have switched off their speakers, which would eventually fail my attempt on alerting the user. So, highlighting the tab as many applications commonly do would be great but I'm not finding any proper way to do it with JavaScript. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can use the `onBeforeUnload` method but will not work on a **SPA** (single page app.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: So update the title of the page?